# Is the question "Does KFC have a queue?" strictly correct?

Tags: nouns, questions, abstract-nouns

As a non-English speaker dabbling in Natural Language Processing, I'm trying to generate meaningful Yes/No-question based in hotel and restaurant reviews. This includes 2 types of "exists" questions: "Is/Are there ... at KFC?" and "Does KFC have ...?" I can see that in some case they cannot be used interchangeably. for example, here works both

- Are there parking lots at KFC?
- Does KFC have parking lots?

However, in the next example there sounds something off with the "Does ... have ..." question:

- Is there a good experience at KFC?
- Does KFC have a good experience?

That clearly has different meanings, and I understand that my 2 types of "exists" questions are semantically equal, in general.

Now I was trying to figure out how I can decide which type of question I can form depending on the "exits" noun (here, "parking lots", "experience"). Intuitively, I thought I can do this be check if the noun is an "abstract entity" or a "physical entity". WordNet gives me this information. Thus, with "experience" being an abstract entity, I can say that "Does KFC has a good experience?" does not work.

However, I now noticed that words like "queue" and "service" are also considered abstract entities, but to me the following questions sounds quite alright:

- Does KFC have a queue?
- Does KFC have a good service?

Do these question only sound correct or are they really correct (in the most picky sense). Because if so, simply looking whether the noun is an abstract or physical entity won't do. In this case, how else can I (programmatically) decide when "Is/Are there ...?" and "Do/Does ... have ...?" can be used interchangeably.

Comment: The grammar: Does KFC *has* a good experience? Should be "**have**"... regardless, it needs to be reworded to "*Is eating at KFC enjoyable?*" OR "*Is eating at KFC a pleasant experience?*" How can a restaurant "be" a good experience? Good experience for someone who has never eaten out before?

Comment: You could say 'Does KFC _provide_ good service [etc.]?'

Comment: Yes, sorry, that "has" was a typo. I know that "Does KFC have a good experience?" needs to be reworded. That's kind of my overall questions: Given the sentence structure "Does KFC have X?" what nouns (optionally with adjective) can I use that it makes sense. X="a clean toilet" works, while X="a good experience" does not. In contrast, for the sentence "Is there X at KFC" both examples work (in my opinion).

Comment: @KateBunting True! But that would require that I also decide which verb to select. Remember, I'm trying to generate questions automatically with hopefully reasonable simple kind of templates.

Comment: "generate questions automatically"? What? You mean the programme creates the questions itself? So every question has to have the same verb? That will never work. The short answer to the question in the title is "Yes". Does it necessarily mean what you think it does? "No".

Comment: 'Correct' is ill-defined in these instances. Many wouldn't consider Chomsky's famous (fully grammatical) sentence 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' totally acceptable. 'Is there a queue at KFC?' (only asked of a person who had passed the establishment in the last few minutes) and 'Is there usually a queue at KFC?' are the variants I'd consider idiomatic in the UK. 'Does KFC have a queue?' would sound at least unusual. 'Does KFC have good service?' is again at least unusual. 'What's the service like at KFC?'  would be used by most Brits.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not arbitrary question, of course. But in my pretty limited context it does work not too bad right now. Sure, there are mistakes regarding indefinite articles and prepositions. And some questions sound a bit odd. You can see some examples here [https://i.imgur.com/tEeGtq4.png](https://i.imgur.com/tEeGtq4.png)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! That's good to know what sounds unusual to native speakers.

Comment: Any native speaker worth his or her salt would snub those questions. Just one example: `Does the room by Novotel Singapore Clarke Quay have small size?` Is that an awfully constructed question? *Yes* :) Is it grammatical? *Barely*. Does it make sense? *Possibly*. Would I continue reading or using this service? *No*.

Comment: And this one `Do the foods in Creperie Entre-Nous have a good variety?` That is not grammatical, it is not English. How can  "foods" *have* a good variety? And `Does the chicken have a good menu?` Perfect Engrish if you ask me. Sorry, but the questions are simply bad.

Comment: @Mari-Lou That analysis sounds much more populist than merely citing the 'Quirk-Svartvik Likert-type scale of acceptability'. But my comment bank is getting rather full.

Comment: Oh, I can fit in one more :)

Comment: The main problem is that the generator believes adjectives should always precede a noun, that's not the case, e.g. "Is the chicken tasty?" is grammatical, but (for example) "Is the good chicken on the tasty menu?" is nonsensical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA All your criticism is truly appreciated. I'm aware that many questions are correct and/or have proper style. Hence my question to first improve "my" English to then improve the generator. And no worries, these questions will never see the light of day :). But for a project I need a couple of hundred thousands or more questions that are not half bad. And based on these comments, I can already make useful adjustments. Thanks for that!

Comment: Like Mari-Lou, I read the whole list and I'm sorry to say that all but one question would be unacceptable to any English-speaking polster, editor, producer or (native) client.

The sole survivor is *Does the York Hotel have parking spaces?* which sadly is still pointless. The hotelier might pay money to find out whether guests thought there was *adequate* parking but providing one or two spaces would invalidate the question.

That you've got so far seems magnificent but why are you trying this in English, please? Why not do it in your native language then have the output translated?